# MySQL "create table" does not work in docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I make docker image with mysql.

I created `init.sql` file to create table when starting docker file.

but after building docker image, table is not created.

I want to create table via `DockerFile` or `docker-compose`.

Here is source code in github.
https://github.com/jpskgc/article

I created `int.sql` file and `docker-compose.yml` to use this `init.sql`file.

```
article
　├ db
　│  └ init.sql
　│  
　└ docker-compose.yml
```

```
//docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: article
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

```sql
//init.sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS article;
use article;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, uuid varchar(36), `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,`content` TEXT NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
create table IF NOT EXISTS images (id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, article_uuid varchar(36), image_name varchar(50));
```

I want to create table in the process of `docker-compose up --build`.
After command `docker-compose up --build` and assess to 'http://localhost:3000/', there is error in backend, which suggesting that table does not exist.

```
api_1     | 2019/07/31 06:29:58 [Recovery] 2019/07/31 - 06:29:58 panic recovered:
api_1     | GET /api/articles HTTP/1.1
api_1     | Host: localhost:2345
api_1     | Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
api_1     | Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
api_1     | Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
api_1     | Connection: keep-alive
api_1     | Origin: http://localhost:3000
api_1     | Referer: http://localhost:3000/
api_1     | User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
api_1     | 
api_1     | 
api_1     | Error 1146: Table 'article.articles' doesn't exist
api_1     | /app/main.go:90 (0xb1c6d1)
api_1     |     main.func2: panic(err.Error())
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x8f97c9)
api_1     |     (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/recovery.go:83 (0x90d259)
api_1     |     RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x8f97c9)
api_1     |     (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/logger.go:240 (0x90c300)
api_1     |     LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/context.go:147 (0x8f97c9)
api_1     |     (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:391 (0x9036c9)
api_1     |     (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
api_1     | /go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/gin.go:352 (0x902dbd)
api_1     |     (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774 (0x6dcc77)
api_1     |     serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878 (0x6d8860)
api_1     |     (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
api_1     | /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337 (0x45a090)
api_1     |     goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
api_1     | 
api_1     | [GIN] 2019/07/31 - 06:29:58 | 500 |    123.5997ms |      172.18.0.1 | GET      /api/articles
```

Comment: Where do you actually execute the int.sql?

Comment: could you please add the logs `docker logs db`

Comment: Maybe in your volumes directive in docker-compose.yml : - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

Comment: >Nico I changed volumes directive as you suggested and run command `docker-compose up --build`. But same error occurs.

Comment: try to connect to your mysql instance via command line : mysql -u root -p --port=3306 and then execute show databases; => what's happening ?

Comment: >Nico There are 5 databases. `article`, `information_schema`, `mysql`, `performance_schema`, `sys`.

Comment: and now if you enter : use article; and after you enter : show tables; and then : describe articles; select * from articles; => do you see your table articles ? (and a question : do you have a local instance of mysql on your computer, not inside a docker ? Maybe a local instance that is already using port 3306 and create a port confusion...)

Comment: `show tables;` -> Empty set (0.01 sec) , `describe articles;` -> `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'article.articles' doesn't exist`, `select * from articles;` ->  `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'article.articles' doesn't exist`

Comment: and I checked port 3306 & kill it. But after `docker-compose up --build`, same error occurs.

Comment: hmmm we are close to the problem, retry the command line mysql -u root -p --port=3306 and then use article; and now try to execute the missing part of your init.sql script in order to verify this part has a valid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative solution, I changed server side codes to create table.

```
    _, err = db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS article;")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Exec("use article;")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (`id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,uuid varchar(36), `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,`content` TEXT NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Exec("create table IF NOT EXISTS images (id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, article_uuid varchar(36), image_name varchar(50)); ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```